# Traversing a 2D array in four directions (up, down, left, right)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a method for traversing a square 2-dimensional array which takes in a parameter that specifies the direction, either up, down, left or right. I've been able to split the task into two separate methods; one for traversing vertically and one for traversing horizontally:

```
private void concatHorizontal(boolean left) {
        int rowIndex, columnIndex, index;
        for (int i=0; i<board.size(); i++) {
            index = (left) ? 0 : board.get(0).size()-1;

            for (int j=0; j<board.get(0).size(); j++) {
                if (left) {
                    rowIndex = i;
                    columnIndex = j;
                } else {
                    rowIndex = board.size() - 1 - i;
                    columnIndex = board.get(0).size() - 1 - j;
                }

                int val = board.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex).getValue();
                if (val != 0) {
                    board.get(rowIndex).get(index).setValue(val);
                    if (columnIndex != index) {
                        board.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex).setValue(0);
                    }
                    index = (left) ? index+1 : index-1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void concatVertical(boolean up) {
        int rowIndex, columnIndex, index;
        for (int i=0; i<board.get(0).size(); i++) {
            index = (up) ? 0 : board.size()-1;

            for (int j=0; j<board.size(); j++) {
                if (up) {
                    columnIndex = i;
                    rowIndex = j;
                } else {
                    columnIndex = board.get(0).size() - 1 - i;
                    rowIndex = board.size() - 1 - j;
                }

                int val = board.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex).getValue();
                if (val != 0) {
                    board.get(index).get(columnIndex).setValue(val);
                    if (rowIndex != index) {
                        board.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex).setValue(0);
                    }
                    index = (up) ? index+1 : index-1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The methods shifts all values in an array not equal to zero as far as possible in a given direction, like in the [game 2048](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMOjvnVdsZY) but without merging neighbors with the same value.

As you can see my code is neither intuitive nor compact, and I would like to merge the two methods above into one if possible. It should, in other words, traverse the arraylist like one of the for-loops below depending on the given direction.

```
        for (int i=0; i<board.size(); i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<board.get(0).size(); j++) {
                // Traverse to the right
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<board.size(); i++) {
            for (int j=board.get(0).size()-1; j>=0; j--) {
                // Traverse to the left
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<board.get(0).size(); i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<board.size(); j++) {
                // Traverse downwards
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<board.get(0).size(); i++) {
            for (int j=board.size()-1; j>=0; j--) {
                // Traverse upwards
            }
        }
```

Comment: `board` does *not* appear to be a "2-dimensional **array**".

Comment: What is your question? Maybe you meant to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Andreas It's a 2-dimensional arraylist. Does array vs arraylist matter here? Also, I'll update the post to make the question clearer.

Comment: In coding, precision/clarity matters, and adding the 4 letters to make it precise is so easy to do. In this case, it doesn't really matter, but `List` vs array can make big differences in other cases, so getting into the habit of being precise would be good.

Comment: You won't get around the fourfold distinction for start value, end value, increment and which index (row, column) to use. You could avoid the ugly ifs in these two methods by setting start, end and increment as parameters.

Comment: Belongs at http://codereview.stackexchange.com as a working code improvement question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *one step* of the solution (with simplified access to the element value):

```
private void concatHori(boolean left) {
    if( left ){
        concatHori( 0, 0, 1 );
    } else {
        concatHori( board.size()-1, board.get(0).size()-1, -1 );
    }
}

private void concatHori(int rowstart, int colstart, int inc ) {
    for (int i=0; i<board.size(); i++) {
        int index = colstart;
        for (int j=0; j<board.get(0).size(); j++) {
            int rowIndex = rowstart + inc*i;
            int colIndex = colstart + inc*j;
            int val = board.get(rowIndex).get(colIndex);
            if (val != 0) {
                board.get(rowIndex).set(index, val);
                if (colIndex != index) {
                    board.get(rowIndex).set(colIndex, 0);
                }
                index += inc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "vertical" method can be transformed in the same way.

The second step would be the union of Horizontal and Vertical, which could be done by providing access functions to the - then - single method. But I think that the resulting code would be more lines and less intuitive that what there is now, and therefore I refrain from adding step 2.

Comment: Yes, this is probably as good as it gets, unless it is somehow possible to specify all the for-loop operators (`int i=0; i<board.size(); i++`) as parameters?

Comment: Well, Java 8 has functions, so you could probably come up with a single algorithm. Probably need to wrap the array into a class with a single access function get(r,c) so that this can be passed in via a functional. But it'll just create more code than you have now (with my meager improvement).